# Error in running test case using batch file via selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I used Selenium IDE firefox plugin to record a test case then i used '.bat' command line to automate testing using the below command,

```
java -jar C:\Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://16.52.110.123:8080/AntExample/userRegistration.htm" "C:\Selenium\First_Test_Real_Suite.html" "C:\selenium\logs\Result.html"
```

the test was perfectly working using the .bat script when suddenly today I am facing this error message in firefox when I run the script

> Firefox can't find the file at
>   chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html?auto=true&multiWindow=true&defaultLogLevel=info&baseUrl=http://16.52.110.123:8080/AntExample/userRegistration.htm&resultsUrl=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/postResults&test=http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/tests/First_Test_Real_Suite.html.

I am all ears to fix this issue

Comment: I observed that issue is in this sector in path:

Comment: chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html while it should be chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/TestRunner.html

How to automatically set it to run the correct path ?

Comment: Looks like this is broken again on Firefox 48. I think the eventual solution will likely be to upgrade to selenium-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar.

Sources:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2616
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127682/how-do-i-run-or-migrate-an-html-test-suite-in-selenium-3

Standalone runner 2.53.0 was working with FF 47 earlier today, before FF automatically upgraded.

Comment: Also relevant: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this issue due to latest Firefox browser update :)

> First Download and Install Previous Firefox Browser Version 42.0 (Link
>   : [Click here](http://filehippo.com/download_firefox/64266))

and Try to execute same Selenium Test cases using Bat file. It will work properly. :)

Also after Installing Firefox browser, Don't forgot to set following option

> Goto Tools >> Options >> Advanced Tab >> Update Tab >> select "Never
>   check for updates (not recommended: security risk)" option to disable
>   auto update.

Running Selenium Test cases using bat file will work properly once new "Selenium Standalone Server" version get released (Current version is 2.48.2 will work for Firefox 42.0)

Answer (score 0):

upgrade/downgrade to FF 42.0 fixed the error. Thnx guys

Comment: May be this should be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed because Firefox 43 doesn't allow you to run unsigned add-ons. If you insist on using the old Selenium RC Runner and want to run the latest Firefox, you can enable add-ons again by allowing for unsigned add-ons:

- In Firefox go to about:config
- Look for setting xpinstall.signatures.required and toggle it to false

Now **any** unsigned add-on will run, including the Selenium RC Runner. Use it at your own risk ;-)