# How do I run or migrate an html test suite in Selenium 3?

Tags: java, bash, unit-testing, selenium

It appears that Firefox has recently been updated, now at version 48.0, causing my -htmlSuite tests to fail. I'm getting this error message from Firefox:

```
Firefox can’t find the file at chrome://src/content/TestRunner.html
```

I'm currently using Selenium Server version 2.53.1 in order to run my tests which were recorded in the Firefox Selenium IDE add-on, then automated on my OS X development server.

The purpose of these tests is to provide a daily synopsis of any websites which need to be reviewed in the event that the script is not able to navigate to the end of the site's purchase workflow. Here is a bash script that I wrote to launch my functional tests:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
     -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.insureone.com"
                "/SeleniumTests/InsureOne-Suite.html" 
                "/SeleniumTests/InsureOne-Results.html" > /dev/null

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
      -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.aaffordableauto.com"            
       "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Suite.html" 
       "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Results.html" > /dev/null

echo "Finished"
```

Here's a snippet from InsureOne Suite's only test, that navigates through the first two pages:

```
InsureOne-Test
setTimeout  60000   
open    /   
sendKeys    id=zipcode  60610
sendKeys    id=phone    3126548045
select  id=year label=2006
waitForElementPresent   //option[contains(.,'PONTIAC')] 
select  id=make label=PONTIAC
waitForElementPresent   //option[contains(.,'G6')]  
select  id=model    label=G6
clickAndWait    //button[contains(.,'Free Quote')]  
setTimeout  120000  
waitForElementPresent   id=getquote 
setTimeout  60000   
clickAndWait    id=getquote
```

These tests are run with Automator, then the results are emailed to me each morning for review.

I had originally attempted to use the latest build of Selenium to launch my tests, but was unable to get that working. I've not been able to find anything in the Selenium docs to help me run an html test suite using the latest build of Selenium.

I don't want the added complexity of automated builds and formal unit tests running in Jenkins + Maven or the equivalent in another language. Is there a way to do this in Selenium 3 from a shell script?

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar  
      -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://www.aaffordableauto.com"            
       "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Suite.html" 
       "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Results.html" > /dev/null
```

This command results in a NullPointerException. I'm stuck because there is no advice on SeleniumHQ about how to either get this working or migrate it to work on the newest release.

Comment: You might want to check out this open bug: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2616

Comment: I tried getting it to run against Firefox Developer Edition as well, with xpinstall.signatures.required set to false (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct), with no success. It launches but for some reason the test suite file is wrong.

java -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox /Applications/FirefoxDeveloperEdition.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "baseURL" "/path/to/test/suite" "/results/file"

Comment: I've been told by the Selenium developers that Selenium 3 Beta 3 will include a legacy jar file for running htmlSuite scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet another workaround, switching to the ChromeDriver allowed me to get the tests working on selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1 again. I did have to modify my bash script to ignore the ssl error caused by Selenium's proxy certificate.

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar 
     -trustAllSSLCertificates 
     -htmlSuite "*googlechrome" "http://www.aaffordableauto.com"
                "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Suite.html" 
                "/SeleniumTests/A-Affordable-Results.html" > /dev/null

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
     -trustAllSSLCertificates
     -htmlSuite "*googlechrome" "http://www.insureone.com"
                "/SeleniumTests/InsureOne-Suite.html"
                "/SeleniumTests/InsureOne-Results.html" > /dev/null

echo "Finished"
```